# How to prove this version of Hoeffding inequality?

Tags: probability-inequalities, hoeffdings-inequality

Based on my studies, Hoeffding inequality is used for bounded or sub-Gaussian random variables which are explained on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) page. I am reading the book [Introduction to Multi-Armed Bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.07272.pdf) by Aleksandrs Slivkins. In page 161, he provides a general inequality without the assumption that a random variable is bounded or subgaussian and calls it Hoeffding inequality. I am wondering how it is possible to prove it.

[image]